# How to remove top-right and bottom-right rounded corners in ModalNavigationDrawer() component in Material3?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

Check in the image below:

[image: ModalNavigationDrawer]

I tried this but not worked.

```
ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            ModalDrawerSheet(
                //case-1
                modifier = Modifier.clip(RectangleShape), //<--- It draws a shape in background of drawer.
                //or
                //case-2
                modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White), //<--- It draws a color in background of drawer.
            ) {
                //Drawer Items here
            }
        },
        content = {
            //Scaffold here
        }
    )
```

You can see official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#ModalNavigationDrawer(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.DrawerState,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function0)) of ModalNavigationDrawer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ModalDrawerSheet` has a `drawerShape` option:

```
ModalDrawerSheet(
    drawerShape = RectangleShape,
) {
    //Drawer Items here
}
```